# Shuffle array (seg fault)

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

So I am supposed to create a function that accomplishes:
Purpose: program to shuffle the lines of a text file

- Read the file into an array
- Count lines and maximum length
- Compute maximum width for array
- Get file pointer to the beginning
- Reserve memory for a dynamic array of strings
- Read a line and store in allocated memory
- Turn the \n into \0
- Print lines from array (test)
- Shuffle array
- Print lines from array (test)
- Free memory and close file

(just to give some background)

However, when I go to print the shuffled array, I get segmentation faults. Occasionally, it prints one or two of the strings, but sometimes It just says "Shuffled Array" and then I get a segmentation fault. Any ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

// Accepts: command line input
// Returns: 0 if no error

int main(int argc, char *argv[] ){
    int x = 0, i, lineCount = 0, maxLen = 0;
    char line[500], temp;
    FILE *file = fopen( argv[1], "r" );
//  check if file exists
    if (file == NULL){
        printf("Cannot open file\n");
        return 1;
    }
//  Gets lines, max length of string    
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) != NULL){
        lineCount++;
        if (strlen(line) > maxLen)
            maxLen = strlen(line);
    }
    rewind(file);
    char *lineArray[lineCount];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) != NULL) {
            lineArray[x] = malloc(strlen(line));
        if (lineArray[x] == NULL){
            printf("A memory error occurred.\n");
            return(1);
        }
            strcpy(lineArray[x], line);
//  change \n to \0
        lineArray[x][strlen(lineArray[x])-1] = '\0';
        x++;
    }
    printf("File %s has %d lines with maximum length of %d characters\n",
        argv[1], lineCount, maxLen);
    printf("Original Array\n");
    for (x = 0; x < lineCount; x++)
        printf("%2d %s\n", x, lineArray[x]);
//  Shuffle array
    srand( (unsigned int) time(NULL));
    for (x = lineCount - 1; x >= 0; x--){
        i = (int) rand() % lineCount;
        temp = lineArray[x];
        lineArray[x] = lineArray[i];
        lineArray[i] = temp;
    }
    printf("\nShuffled Array\n");
    for (x = 0; x < lineCount; x++)
        printf("%2d %s\n", x, lineArray[x]);
//  free allocated memory
    for (x = 0; x < lineCount; x++)
        free(lineArray[x]);
    free(lineArray);
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens if you hard-code the input strings, instead of trying to read them from a file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [File input into array by line as string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19619343/file-input-into-array-by-line-as-string)

Comment: you already asked this, go do your homework

Comment: @Vorsprung I have been working on this for a while and my compiler isn't coming up with warnings.

Comment: @WorldDominator C requires a compiler to issue warnings in this situation. Check again because if you have no warning then you are not using a C compiler.

Comment: so get a compiler that works.  gcc is free

Comment: @Vorsprung I'm using gcc on my college's servers and what I had above produced no errors or warnings when I compiled.

Comment: Add the `-Wall` flag when you compile, frankly, you should always use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output from running `cc` on my machine makes the error pretty obvious.

```
$ cc tmp.c -o tmp
tmp.c:46:14: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to
      'char' from 'char *'; dereference with * [-Wint-conversion]
        temp = lineArray[x];
             ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
               *
tmp.c:48:22: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to
      'char *' from 'char'; take the address with & [-Wint-conversion]
        lineArray[i] = temp;
                     ^ ~~~~
                       &
2 warnings generated.
```

You need to fix your variables, you can't use a `char` where you intend to use a `char *`.

Sorry, to make it more clear:

```
char line[500], temp;
```

should be:

```
 char line[500], *temp;
```

If you want clarification on why this is, let me know.

Lastly, it is not C-style (unless you are writing embedded C) to declare variables at the top of a method. Declare them as close to the usage point as possible. It makes it easier to find what you declared. For example, `temp` could be declared right above the loop where its used, or even better, in the loop itself.

Oh, and :

```
$ cc --version
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.76) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: Oh, the exact reason for segfault, converting a pointer (`char *`) to a char will cause data loss, thus completely invalidating the pointer; since a pointer is just an `int`.

Comment: *a pointer is just an int* this is wrong and there is absolutely no guarantee an `int` can hold a pointer value.

Comment: A pointer is an `unsigned int` on all platforms. The size of this may vary, you are correct I forgot the unsigned part. But, this is a POSIX standard, but unfortunately not a C standard. Hard to find a modern compiler that doesn't hold this, though.

Comment: Thank you. I get confused with pointers and I don't care much for the gcc compiler. I seem to have the required I/O with what you gave for help.

Comment: @Nava2 *A pointer is an unsigned int on all platforms* This is wrong in C and in POSIX. How could a 32-bit `unsigned int` in a 64-bit system hold a pointer in a 64-bit address space?

Comment: You are correct, it is `unsigned long`, as I just verified by writing a small set of prints. This will always be the case on modern compilers, and I'm done with this discussion. 

@WorldDominator glad I could help.

Comment: "it is unsigned long" -- no, it isn't ... an implementation can have 32-bit pointers and 64-bit longs. " I just verified by writing a small set of prints" -- gee, I thought you said in was in the POSIX standard ... why not just quote that? "I'm done with this discussion" -- that's one way to deal with being wrong.

Comment: No, it's frustrating when trying to talk to someone who is new and yes, it is an over-simplification, and yes it is implementation dependent. POSIX discussion, http://stackoverflow.com/a/1474667/1748595, simple test I ran on OSX (http://codepad.org/Vh3nkpId), I'm not sure what compiler this site uses, but its definitely 32-bit.

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing here?

```
free(lineArray);
```

`lineArray` is an array, defined as so:

```
char *lineArray[lineCount];
```

You shouldn't try to `free()` it, because you didn't `malloc()` it in the first place.

On top of that, this:

```
char line[500], temp;
```

should be this:

```
char line[500], *temp;
```

as your compiler should be trying to tell you.

There may be other problems, but since you choose not to provide your input file or to provide a version of your program that doesn't need one, nobody can compile and run it to find out.

EDIT: Making the above changes, changing `lineArray[x] = malloc(strlen(line));` to `lineArray[x] = malloc(strlen(line) + 1);` as suggested by another answer, and using a suitable input file, I get the following output:

```
paul@local:~/src/c/scratch$ ./sta testfile
File testfile has 4 lines with maximum length of 13 characters
Original Array
 0 john doe
 1 jane fish
 2 donny brutus
 3 fishy mcgee

Shuffled Array
 0 john doe
 1 jane fish
 2 fishy mcgee
 3 donny brutus
paul@local:~/src/c/scratch$
```

You seriously need to learn to use your compiler better, though. You should be invoking gcc like this:

```
gcc -o myprog myfile.c -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra
```

to get all the most useful warnings.

Comment: I apologize for this. The file we are using just has last, then first names of myself and other classmates on separate lines.